# Netflow sample data sets

Tags: netflow

Does anyone know of an open netflow data set, I want to use it to run a little experiment on it, and analyse some of the flows. I looked around but there is nothing. Or if there is a good method to capture netflow data without actually having a cisco router.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You best/quickest option is to generate NetFlow through a software exporter that uses live capture (see for instance nProbe: http://www.ntop.org/products/netflow/nprobe/ or FlowTraq's free exporter:  http://www.flowtraq.com/corporate/product/flow-exporter/).

Both these software exporters also have the capability to generate netflow from PCAP files.  This can be convenient if you either have PCAP files, or download PCAP datasets, which are much more available than netflow datasets.